pulseaudio can not remember balance setting for apps when I use headphones
pulseaudio screenshot
My pulseaudio cannnot save my Front-LEFT and Front-RIGHT volume setting for headphone when I plugin in headphone I have to rebalance them.
But pulseaudio can remember rhythmbox, but not for chrome and microsoft edge, VLC etc. Does anyone how to fix it?
